# Does Firebase Function Does not Support Node 18 as its Engine parameter in Package.json file?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, package.json, react-typescript

Does firebase function supports node 18 version as its engine parameters in package.json file. I am getting error as " Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. Valid choices are: {"node": 10|12|14|16}" when i used Node 18 as engine parameter.

I tried to use node 18 in engine parameter field as

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
```

my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "watch": "webpack --watch --mode development",
    "serve": "npm run build && firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "fmt": "prettier --config '../.prettierrc' --write 'src/**/*.{tsx,ts}'"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@bugsnag/js": "^7.10.1",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^5.18.2",
    "@google-cloud/tasks": "2.5.0",
    "@slack/web-api": "^5.7.0",
    "@types/axios": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.1",
    "@types/node": "^13.1.7",
    "async-sema": "3.0.1",
    "axios": "^0.26.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "date-fns": "1.30.1",
    "date-fns-timezone": "^0.1.4",
    "delay": "4.3.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-basic-auth": "1.2.0",
    "firebase-admin": "^8.13.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.19.0",
    "fp-ts": "^1.18.2",
    "freee-firebase-sdk": "^2.0.6",
    "freee-logger": "git+https://github.com/freee/freee-logger.git",
    "http": "^0.0.0",
    "maskdata": "^1.1.6",
    "node-cache": "^5.1.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.2",
    "nodemailer-sendgrid-transport": "0.2.0",
    "oauth": "^0.9.15",
    "ramda": "^0.26.1",
    "simple-oauth2": "^2.2.1",
    "url": "0.11.0",
    "json-bigint": "^1.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "minimist": "^1.2.6",
    "node-forge": "^1.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.7",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.1.6",
    "jest": "^26.0.0",
    "jest-cli": "^26.0.0",
    "omega-js": "git+ssh://git@github.com/C-FO/omega-js.git#v1.0.1",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.0.0",
    "ts-loader": "^5.4.3",
    "tslint": "^5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this by updating to the latest firebase cli version. I was on v11.16.1 and then upgraded to v11.24.0.

See instructions on how to upgrade here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cli

Comment: Did you test it with emulator or do it directly on firestore server? I have problem with emulator.

Comment: Tested! It's worked for me with emulator.

Comment: Hmm im getting a permission error even when I use the sudo command. Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation at [Set Node.js version](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#set_nodejs_version) says:

> Firebase SDK for Cloud Functions 2.0.0 and higher allows a selection
> of Node.js runtime. You can choose to run all functions in a project
> exclusively on the runtime environment corresponding to one of these
> supported Node.js versions:
>
> - Node.js 18
> - Node.js 16
> - Node.js 14
>
> #### Upgrade your Node.js runtime
>
> To upgrade your Node.js runtime:
>
> Make sure your project is on the Blaze pricing plan.
>
> - Make sure you are using Firebase CLI v9.17.0 or later.
> - Change the engines value in the package.json file that was created in your functions/ directory during initialization. For example, if you are upgrading from version 16 to version 18, the entry should look like this: `"engines": {"node": "18"}`
> - Optionally, test your changes using the Firebase Local Emulator Suite.
> - Redeploy functions using the Firebase CLI v11.18.0 or later.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I have checked the Docs and used node 18 but in my console i am getting error as not supported . Error: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. Valid choices are: {"node": 10|12|14|16}

Comment: What CLI version? Blaze plan?

Comment: firebase CLI -V : 11.19.0 , yes Blaze Plan.

Comment: Lots of dependencies in your package.json file. Maybe try and deploy a basic Hello World app w no dependencies with Node version set to 18 and see if that works?

Comment: sure , will try to check .Thank you

Comment: @kumarprashant I'm dealing with the same issue with a simpler app. How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

As @user1094929 said I tested with updated versions of `firebase cli` and `firebase-functions`

- firebase-cli: v11.24.0
- firebase-functions: v3.18.0

After that, the emulator works with `node version v18.12.1`.

As an additional note, as if you are using `Typescript` remember build file to get `index.js` file.

[image]

You can check the emulator URL in logs when the emulator starts.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Also check your local nodejs version. If you use nvm, try to change your local nodejs version to v16 or v18.