# Firebase doesn't accept nodejs 18. Failed to load function error

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I am trying to launch cloud functions based on this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDMDpdu5-rE. When I try to run `firebase emulators:start` I get `Failed to load function definition from source: FirebaseError: package.json in functions directory has an engines field which is unsupported. Valid choices are: {"node": 10|12|14|16}`. How can I resolve this issue? I updated everything following the guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started

```
npm install firebase-functions@latest firebase-admin@latest --save
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

only with yarn instead of npm. Still I get the same error. Firebase version seems to be at `firebase-tools@11.24.1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out by trying out some things from [Does Firebase Function Does not Support Node 18 as its Engine parameter in Package.json file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74870609/does-firebase-function-does-not-support-node-18-as-its-engine-parameter-in-packa). For some reason in package.json the value `"engines": {"node": ">= 16"}` produced this behavior. Setting it to `"engines": {"node": "18"}` resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can try to upgrade your firebase cli to the latest version. Usually that works as well.

```
npm -g install firebase-tools@latest
```